# Images not loading in macOS 12 & iOS 15 Mail app

Tags: email, ssl-certificate, ios15, macos-monterey

Around 3 weeks ago we realized images in our newsletter were not loading when opened in macOS 12 & iOS 15 Mail. When opened in different email apps, and in different versions of macOS/iOS Mail, the images would load with no problem. Switching from hosting the images on our usual, shared, server to hosting in Mailchimp also fixed the issue. The images are inserted in an img element's src attribute.

Unchecking "Block All Remote Content" in Mail's privacy settings did not fix the issue. We've downgraded our TLS to 1.2, [as suggested in this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253359290), but that did not fix the issue.

Below are screenshots of the emails in Mail - not working, Gmail - working.

macOS/Mail
[image: macOS/Mail]

macOS/GMail
[image: macOS/GMail]

Image hosted on shared server - https://www.tjcresources.net/images/FINAL_Birthday_email.jpg

Image hosted on Mailchimp - https://mcusercontent.com/ef8c6666869c429f75ebf2f2b/images/1bba5438-ed06-45f9-2a4a-853facde56fe.jpg

Comment: Do you have any updates on this?

Comment: We upgraded the SSL cert on the shared server and that did not fix the issue. We ended up migrating our content hosted on the shared server to a dedicated server and it fixed the issue. I don't have an answer as to why that fixed the issue, or what it was about our shared server that was causing this problem.

Comment: This is so freaking weird. I did upload the photos to Amazon S3 and they are now being displayed, but this is not a good solution. We need to find out what is the problem.